# position: absolute only for one div

Tags: html, css

I have some place for drag-and-drop

```
<ul class="droppable two-lines-head " data-id="2" id="middle-level">
    <div class="mutedhelptextmedium">@ProfileResources.AdvancedSkillHelper</div>
</ul>
```

div class="mutedhelptextmedium" performs the placeholder function.And im draging tags to this field,as a result, my placeholder text drop down,giving place for element

```
<li class="tech-add-skill-row technology-name isNotApproved" id="3" 
style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; max-width: 228px;">
            xml
<i class="deleteicon"></i></li>
```

if i add position:absolute to a tag(LI).All will be ok,except another tag will be stratify each other (need relative position for tags.).So how i can implement absolution position only between LI and text?i'm trying z-index but something go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `absolute` position to a parent wrapper:

```
<ul style="position:absolute;">

 <li class="tech-add-skill-row technology-name isNotApproved" id="3" 
 style="position: relative; opacity: 1; max-width: 228px;">
        xml
 <i class="deleteicon"></i></li>

 <li class="tech-add-skill-row technology-name isNotApproved" id="3" 
 style="position: relative; opacity: 1; max-width: 228px;">
        xml
 <i class="deleteicon"></i></li>

</ul>
```

Now they won't *stratify*

Comment: I cant post images,but tags still drop down my "muted" text,they must strratify on text,but not on each other

Comment: problem solved,i just needed set absolute position to ul and to div with text,thanks)